# SQL Server 2000 Server Errors

Tags: c#, sql-server

The same database and application acts weirdly on our test machine, but it works nice on other computers.

On the test machine:

- We get SSL error exception. We fixed that based on an MS KB article, but after that it said
- "`Server error`" or "`General network error`" and slowed down to 1-2 stored procedures/second.
- The profiler said that we have 2000-2500 connections when the application runs. The same application has only 5-10 connection on other machines. I think the random error messages are caused by this huge connection count.

We reinstalled SQL Server, turned off the connection pool, and closed all datareaders.

What else can I do? Is there a "deeper" configuration tool for MSSQL2k? Any hidden component/ini/config/registry key? Or another profiler other than SQL Profiler that I can use?

Comment: Have you checked the windows and sql server event logs?

Comment: What service pack is your SQL2K on test machine? Do you have same service pack on all boxes?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx again Mitch, sadly none of those ideas was real solution. No suprise - it seems that those error messages from MSSQL are *random*.

*Random*, I mean:

- After X[1] concurrent connection MSSQL stops to close connections automatically, and the connection pool grooves huge. Before X, I saw only 5-10 connections[2] / but after that there was 2500 and MSSQL chrased.
- In this case, MSSQL throws non deterministic error messages like *'General failure'*, *'User (null)'* etc.
- We had unclosed connection in our DAL (hidden since 2 years...brrr), and when we used that to much, it caused this wreid error.

[1] I have no idea about concrete value of X

[2] I've used this query:

```
    SELECT 
      DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
      COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
      loginame as LoginName 
    FROM
      sysprocesses
    WHERE 
      dbid > 0
    GROUP BY 
      dbid, loginame
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility(!):

[Multiple Fixes for SQL Server .NET Data Provider](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;823679)

> When the SQLCommand.CommandTimeout is
>   set to zero, you expect an infinite
>   timeout. However, versions 1.1 and 1.0
>   of the SqlClient provider incorrectly
>   timeout when a response from SQL
>   Server is broken into two packets.
>   Immediately upon receipt of the second
>   packet, versions 1.1 and 1.0 of the
>   provider incorrectly timeout. The fix
>   that is included in this article fixes
>   this issue so that the command will
>   have an infinite timeout.

Comment: Thank you, maybe that will work. I'll come back after some tests.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you turn off OLE DB Resource Pooling?:

```
'For SQLOLEDB provider
 'strConnect = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=MyServerName;OLE DB Services = -2;uid=AppUser;pwd=AppUser;initial catalog=northwind"

' For MSDASQL provider 
'strConnect = "DSN=SQLNWind;UID=Test;PWD=Test; OLE DB Services= -2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look at is whether you are always specifying the type and direction of stored procedure parameters from ADO.NET.

What happens internally is sqlClient converts the parameters which you have set in ADO.NET to the relevant datatypes in the stored procedure parameters. But this can fail when you are sending nText parameters where it might result in a wrong conversion.

Also, I would check to see if you are sometimes passing very long statements in stored procedure parameters.